# Elementary embeddings and replacement

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\alpha\not= 0$ be such that for every $\beta<\alpha$ there is $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$, where $V_\gamma$ is an elementary substructure of $V_\alpha$. In other words, $V_\alpha$ is a limit of its $V_\beta$ elementary substructures. Then it is a simple result that $V_\alpha$ models replacement.

My question: Let $\alpha\not= 0$ be such that for every $\beta<\alpha$ there is $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$ and an elementary embedding from $V_\gamma$ to $V_\alpha$. Does it follow that $V_\alpha$ models replacement?

Comment: Oh, you changed the question. I was about to post an answer to the earlier one.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I’m so sorry! The original question is the one I’m interested in ultimately, but I thought the new question would be more accessible. If you have an answer, though, should I just reinstate that question?

Comment: The questions are similar, since you get $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings in the old version by using a universal $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate. I'll try to post an answer a bit later.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Right. But I thought the new question might be more tractable. In fact, the new question is the one I was focusing my attention on when I was thinking this all through.

Comment: Yes, I find the new question more attractive.

Comment: My earlier idea doesn't quite work.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but being an elementary submodel is equivalent to saying that the identity is an elementary embedding. So you're really just weakening the first thing by allowing the elementary embedding to not be the identity. So I'm not sure why Gabe's answer involves supercompacts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That’s right, the assumption is weaker. But getting an elementary embedding between ranks that isn’t the identity requires a lot of large cardinal strength. To show that we can have the assumption without replacement, we need a bunch of elementary embeddings that aren’t the identity and thus a lot of large cardinal strength. (I was working with extendables and Vopkenka’s principle, e.g. to try and get such a model.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a limit of $2^\alpha$-supercompact cardinals,
then by the Magidor characterization of supercompactness, for each $2^\alpha$-supercompact cardinal $\kappa < \alpha$, for some $\gamma < \kappa$, there is an elementary embedding $j : V_{\gamma}\to V_\alpha$ with critical point arbitrarily large below $\kappa$. Thus for each $\beta < \gamma$, there is an elementary embedding $j : V_{\gamma}\to V_\alpha$ such that $\gamma$ is between $\beta$ and the next $\alpha$-supercompact cardinal, which yields the property you asked about.

But if $\alpha$ is the least cardinal  that is a limit of $\alpha$-supercompact cardinals, then $V_\alpha$ does not model replacement: from the perspective of $V_\alpha$, there are $\omega$-many supercompact cardinals that are cofinal in the ordinals. The reason is that the $2^{\alpha}$-supercompacts of $V$ are precisely the supercompacts of $V_\alpha$. Clearly the forwards implication holds, but conversely if $\delta$ is supercompact in $V_\alpha$, then $\delta$ is supercompact up to a cardinal $\kappa < \alpha$ that is $2^\alpha$-supercompact, and as a consequence, $\delta$ itself is $2^\alpha$-supercompact.

The optimal hypothesis is the existence of an ordinal $\alpha$ that is a limit of $\alpha$-Magidor supercompact cardinals, where a cardinal $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Magidor supercompact if for some $\gamma < \kappa$, there is an elementary embedding $j : V_\gamma\to V_\alpha$ such that $\kappa = j(\text{crit}(j))$. Let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal as in your question. Let $\beta$ be the supremum of the $\alpha$-Magidor supercompact cardinals. If $\beta < \alpha$, then fix an elementary embedding $j : V_\gamma\to V_\alpha$ with $\beta < \gamma < \alpha$, and note that $j(\text{crit}(j)) \leq \beta < \gamma$ and hence $j$ witnesses that $\text{crit}(j)$ is huge, contrary to the minimality of $\alpha$. So $\alpha = \beta$ and hence $\alpha$ is a limit of $\alpha$-Magidor supercompact cardinals.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe! That's just what I was looking for. I take it the easiest way to implement your idea is to let $\alpha$ be the limit of the first $\omega$ supercompacts. Then we get that $\beta$ is supercompact in $V_\alpha$ just in case it is supercompact simpliciter and thus that they are the first $\omega$ supercompacts from the perpsective of $V_\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, that works. And after all the theory "ZFC + infinitely many supercompacts" is not really much stronger than "ZFC + the existence of an ordinal $\alpha$ that is a limit of $\alpha$-Magidor supercompacts," which already implies the consistency of Zermelo set theory + infinitely many supercompacts.

Comment: Exactly! And it makes obtaining the relevant limit trivial.